# How to fail a successful Angular JS $http.get() promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

How do I reject or fail a successful $http.get() promise?  When I receive the data, I run a validator against it and if the data doesn't have required properties I want to reject the request.  I know I can do after the promise is resolved, but it seems like a good idea to intercept errors as soon as possible.
*I'm familiar with the benefits of $q, but really want to continue using $http.*

Comment: Under what circumstances will the server send you back invalid data?

Comment: When it's missing properties that my application needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can reject any promise by returning `$q.reject("reason")` to the next chained `.then`.

Same with `$http`, which returns a promise - this could be as follows:

```
return $http.get("data.json").then(function(response){
  if (response.data === "something I don't like") {
    return $q.reject("bad data");
  }
  return response.data;
}
```

This could simply be done within a service, which pre-handles the response with the `.then` as specified above, and returns some data - or a rejection.

If you want to do this at an app-level, you could use $http [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) - this is just a service that provides functions to handle $http requests and responses, and allows you to intercept a response and return either a response - same or modified - or a promise of the response, including a rejection.

```
.factory("fooInterceptor", function($q){
  return {
    response: function(response){
      if (response.data === "something I don't like") {
        return $q.reject("bad data");
      }
      return response;
    }
  }
});
```

Same idea as above - except, at a different level.

Note, that to register an interceptor, you need to do this within a `.config`:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push("fooInterceptor");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AngularJS [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors). But you still need to use $q in them because $http uses $q.

[Here](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/) is a useful article about interceptors.