# Creating a function around angular $http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First project in AngularJS and I started creating my services (factories) that I made modular like this

```
angular.module('app.services.public', [])
    .factory('publicService', ['$http', function publicService($http) {
        var results = {};
        results.contact = function (name, email, message){
             return $http.get();
        };
        return results;
    }]);
```

That I then call in my main angular app by including it. When I call it, I need to listen for success or error

```
publicService.contact().success(callback).error(callback)
```

My question is, I'm going to be doing a lot of API requests through these services and seems to be bad code to listen to the error everytime since 90% of the time it will do the same thing.

How can I create a wrapper around the `$http.get` or around all factory calls?

So something like

```
apiCall = function (url, data, successCallback, errorCallback){
    $http.get(url,data).success(function(){
        successCallback()
    }).error(function(){
        if(errorCallback()){ errorCallback(); return; }
         // or display general error message
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against converting *promise*-based into *callback*-based APIs. Angular adopted promises and it best to stay with them.
Also, stay away from `$http`-specific `.success`/`.error` and use promise `.then`/`.catch` APIs.

**How wide do you need to cast your net to handle `$http` errors?**

**1)** Say, it only applies to your `publicService` service, then you can "handle" it at the each function:

```
.factory("publicService", function($http, $q){ 
    function handleError(){
      // invokes error handlers
    }
    return {

      onError: function(cb){
        // register error handlers
      },
      doSomethingA: function(){
        return $http.get("some/url/A")
                    .then(function(response){
                       return response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function(error){
                       handleError(error);
                       return $q.reject(error); // still "rethrow" the error
                    }
      },
      doSomethingB: function(){
        // similar to above
      },
      // etc...
    };

})
```

Then you could separate request from error handling:

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, publicService){
   publicService.onError(function(error){
     $scope.showError = true; // or something like that
   })
})
.controller("FunctionACtrl", function($scope, publicService){
   publicService.doSomethingA()
                .then(function(data){
                  $scope.data = data;
                });
})
```

**2)** Of course, the above, would only apply to request made via `publicService`. If you want to catch all `$http` errors, you could implement an `$http` interceptors. I won't go into detail - there is enough info in [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) and elsewhere - but it would could work like below:

```
.factory("ErrorService", function(){
  return {
    onError: function(cb){
      // register error handlers
    },
    broadcastError: function(error){
      // invoke error handlers
    }
  };
})
```

Then in interceptor, use `ErrorService` as a dependency:

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {

   ErrorService.broadcastError(rejection);

   return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

Then you could handle the errors globally:

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, ErrorService){
   ErrorService.onError(function(error){
     $scope.showError = true; // or something like that
   })
})
```

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could develop a bit more on the second method.

Comment: @denislexic, there is some boilerplate code around creating interceptors - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29221969/968155) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30383841/968155) for more context

Comment: For reference to other people, this article is pretty good on explaining how it all works: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. You can do it easily with a Factory.

```
myApp.factory(APIService, function(publicService, $http) {
  return {

    // create methods in here
    ...

    contact: function(cb) {
      $http.get(url,data).success(cb).error(function(err){
        console.error('oh no!', err);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then you can use it in your controllers.

```
APIService.contact(function(data){
  console.log('response from the api!', data);
});
```

You can even move your error handler to its own factory as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an implementation using angular's [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service.

```
angular.module('app.services.public', [])
    .factory('publicService', ['$http', '$q', function publicService($http, $q) {
        var results = {};
        results.contact = function (name, email, message){
             return $q.when($http.get());
        };
        return results;
    }]);
```

Or rather than use the `$q.when(...)` method you can use `$q.deferred` like so:

```
angular.module('app.services.public', [])
        .factory('publicService', ['$http', '$q', function publicService($http, $q) {
            var deferred = $q.deferred();
            var results = {};
            results.contact = function (name, email, message){
                 $http.get().success(function(data){
                      deferred.resolve({
                         // assumes data retried from http request has a title and price attribute
                         title: data.title,
                         cost: data.price});
                 }).error(function(data){
                       deferred.reject(data);
                 });
            };
            return deferred.promise;
        }]);
```